# print array multidimensional values

Tags: arrays, printing, arraylist, multidimensional-array

i I have a problem to print array .I received this array of web services by nusoap

How can I display the values ​​of this multidimensional array. I worked with foreach, I could not do it., Please explain with an example. Thanks

my array:

`Array ( [Result] => Array ( [Root] => Array ( [row] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [!R] => 0 [!C1] => 300064 [!C2] => name1 [!C3] => 1287744941 [!C4] => 798 [!C5] => 1338/06/29 [!C6] => [!C7] =>name2 [!C8] =>name2 91 ) [1] => Array ( [!R] => 19 [!C1] => 300064 [!C2] => name1 [!C3] => 1287744941 [!C4] => 798 [!C5] => 1338/06/29 [!C6] => [!C7] =>name2 [!C8] =>name2 92 ) [2] => Array ( [!R] => 38 [!C1] => 300064 [!C2] => name1 [!C3] => 1287744941 [!C4] => 798 [!C5] => 1338/06/29 [!C6] => [!C7] =>name2 [!C8] =>name2 93 ) [3] => Array ( [!R] => 57 [!C1] => 300064 [!C2] => name1 [!C3] => 1287744941 [!C4] => 798 [!C5] => 1338/06/29 [!C6] => [!C7] => name3 [!C8] => name3 ) ) ) ) )`

Comment: I received this array of web services(by nusoap)